# Remote Pushurl won't work

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I'm using GIT for my projects. Now I want to integrate it with github, so I created a remote:

```
git remote add github https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git
```

But now I need to fill in a password for fetching, something that I don't want. So I decided to use a different url for fetching:

```
git remote set-url github http://github.com/WouterJ/project.git
git remote set-url --push github https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git
```

If I run `git remote -v` I get this:

```
$ git remote -v
github  http://github.com/WouterJ/project.git (fetch)
github  https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git (push)
origin  http://github.com/WouterJ/project.git (fetch)
origin  http://github.com/WouterJ/project.git (push)
```

Exactly want I want, I thought. But when I do a push I need to fill in my Username. Why? If I push directly to the url if filled in it works perfectly:

```
git push https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git master
```

Works, but

```
git push github master
```

Won't work

---

I also used the `git config` to set a different push url:

```
git config remote.github.pushurl https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git
```

And if I get the pushurl from the config it looks like it is correct:

```
$ git config remote.github.pushurl
https://WouterJ@github.com/WouterJ/project.git
```

Also looking at the .git/config file it looks like everything is correct.

---

Am I missing something here? Is it a bug? I use Git1.7.4, is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how you can solve this, so to aswer my own question:

The trick is to upload to Git1.7.8 (or higher). Now you get this with the same settings and without a `_netrc` file:

```
$ git push github master
Password for 'https://WouterJ@github.com/':

$ git fetch github
fetching....
```

So it looks like the bug is fixed in Git1.7.8 ([Release Notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L134-137))

Comment: Excellent. +1. I thought you were using Git1.7.4 (which is already higher than 1.7.0 though)

Comment: Wait, I have typed Git1.7.0 but mean Git1.7.10.1 (the latest stable release). Thank you, I will edit it

Comment: Ok, now I get it ;) I was doing tests with 1.7.9 and 1.7.10 without being able to reproduce your issue, so that confirms it.

Comment: @VonC, I have done some more research and it looks like this bug is fixed in 1.7.8 ([Release Notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L134-137))

Answer (score 1):

The only missing piece, in order to push to an https GitHub address, is your `~/.netrc` file (or `%HOME%/_netrc` file on Windows) with your GitHub credentials in it.

See "[Git - How to use `.netrc` file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password/6031266#6031266)".

```
machine github.com
login <login_github>
password <password_github>
```

See other settings at "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't want to save the password. The problem is when I use the url in the `git push` command I only need to typ the password. What is the difference between typing the url or using remotes `pushurl`? Do I understand the `pushurl` wrong?

Comment: @WouterJ `git remote set-url --push` and `git config remote.github.pushurl` should be equivalent. Is it possible you have github defined in another config file (a global or system one, as opposed to your local config file)?

Comment: Both techniques won't work. The url is saved in the correct file. If I change that url to a local repo it works and the url itself works, but the user SSH part of the pushurl won't work.  I also don't know much about git add configs, so a global or system one? What do you mean?

Comment: @WouterJ see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310974/more-than-one-value-for-the-key-user-name-git/4311218#4311218

Comment: if I typ `git config --get-all remote.github.pushurl` I get only the one I have set up for the project. So it looks like there is no github remote in another config file. I have solved it by using the `_netrc` file (but can I save only the username and not the password?)

Comment: @WouterJ I don't know of a way to save only the username, beside including it in the https address, except in your case, it doesn't seem to work... Maybe don't include the `password` field in the `_netrc` file, but it might then ask for username and password.

Comment: thank you for your help. It seems like I couldn't save only the username, so I have saved them both.  Is it a bug that the username in the https address won't work?

Comment: @WouterJ it seems like a bug. Putting only the username should work.