# Git says: More than one value for the key difftool.vs2012.cmd

Tags: windows, git

I ran this command twice today, the second time to experiment with the quotes because the setting didn't seem to have an effect:

```
git config --global difftool.vs2012.cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" -diff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Now when I run this:

```
git config --global --get difftool.vs2012.cmd
```

I get this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
error: More than one value for the key difftool.vs2012.cmd: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Note the error.

Running `git difftool -t vs2012` still doesn't work, but my question is how to remove the apparent duplicate key-value pair in the Git config file somewhere?

While typing this question, I ran the first command again and I now seem to have it 3 times! Why does it keep adding more and more instead of overwriting?

And where is the config file so I can edit it using Notepad instead of this awful, awful command line syntax?

I thought Git was going to be good the way people bang on about it.

P.S. The following question doesn't mention how to resolve it.

[More than one value for the key user.name Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310974/more-than-one-value-for-the-key-user-name-git)

Comment: What version of Git are you using? The latest 1.8.0 msysgit one, I presume?

Comment: Yeah, a colleague on Mac thought it was odd behaviour, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the duplicates, I had to edit `.gitconfig` in my home directory (Windows profile) in a text editor that honors the line-endings.

Git, being a Linux thing, and Linux people thinking that the way they do stuff is in God's vision, they ignore the line-endings of the Windows platform they're running on, so be careful not to mangle the file by using just any text editor on Windows.

Comment: +1 for mentioning where `.gitconfig` is. This was sixt question i was reading.