# Git not showing Author details in commit

Tags: git

when i did git log on my git repository it showing **Author: = <=>**  as author details while in earlier commits it showing me the user name and email.

here is the screen shot of git log.

[image]

and in my earlier commits it is showing something like this

[image]

Comment: Try running `git config --list` on the machine where you did the commit. Are the `user.name` and `user.email` fields set?

Comment: alias.st=status
alias.co=checkout
alias.br=branch
alias.cm=commit
alias.ds=diff
alias.dc=diff
user.email=atul.agrawal9911@gmail.com
user.name=Atul Agrawal
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=<my repo url>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=Atul Agrawal
user.email=atul.polestar@paytm.com

Comment: this is what i got when i did git config --list

Comment: Did you commit using command-line or a GUI tool?

Comment: The fact that you have `user.name` and `user.email` set twice might be a reason for this. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310974/more-than-one-value-for-the-key-user-name-git) can help you,

Comment: I have used phabricator and after review i am landing the branch on master

Comment: @ ComicSansMS: this is because i have different user name for global and for local

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running this if nothing else works when you commit:

```
git commit --author=<author> ...
```

Also, to set default configuration for a machine (recommended by myself), do the following:

```
git config --global "user.name" "Nick Bull"
git config --global "user.email" "nick.bull@email.co.uk"
```

or across the machine you're on (i.e., for all `user`s) do `git config --system "<setting>" "<value>"`.

Note you have duplicate entries in your configuration. Git will apply a "last one wins" approach to these.